# Facebook status update: "Invalid OAuth access token"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Help to understand why the third step (update status) fails:

**request_token (OK):**

```
GET:https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id=XXX&
scope=offline_access,read_stream,publish_stream,user_activities,status_update&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

Got `code`

**access_token (OK):**

```
GET:https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=XXX&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
client_secret=XXX&
code=XXX
```

Got `access_token key` started with *AAA...*

**update status (ERROR):**

```
POST:https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=XXX&message=Hello!
```

**response:**

```
status:{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

What may be the problem?
Or advise any library in C++.

Comment: while getting `access_token` you are passing same `request_token` and secret?

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi, I am sending `code`, which I got from `request_token`

Comment: in redirect url, try add or remove slash from your url. i got same problem before, when i remove the slash, its works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lint your access token at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and tell us what it tells you.

Comment: I don't know, was there more on the linter than that?  Try using your application via the Graph API Explorer tool to ensure it works there.

Comment: Graph API Explorer shows me something like `{
  "id": "XXX",
  "name": "XXX",
  "first_name": "XXX",
  "last_name": "Guinness",
  "link": "XXX",
  "username": "XXX",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "type": "user"
}`

Comment: And when I insert an `access_token`, Graph API Explorer shows me a dialog with checked options: `offline_access,read_stream,publish_stream,user_activities,status_update` So I think the `access_token` is valid.